# How can I view .log files in the output window? Can I redirect task output to the output window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The reason for me asking is that Im working with a build tool that doesnt forward compiler colorization, causing everything to be single colored in the terminal task output view ( and I happen to know that the output window supports automatic colorization of log files).